# Add more columns to GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView`, which is bound to a database table.  This `GridView` shows the some books (price, author information, etc).

I wants to add a column "*Add to Cart*" to this `GridView` at the end of each book.  I added one column with text "Add to cart".  But, on debug, it shows an error as "*Add to cart* is not present in db."

So please tell me how to append this column to the `GridView`.

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Double" 
    BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="260px" 
    Width="661px">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Add To Cart">
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class WebForm9 : System.Web.UI.Page<p>
{
    buybl obj = new buybl();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.dept = "IT";
        GridView1.DataSource = obj.select();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the markup of your `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your markup, it's hard to say.  But, it sounds like you may have modelled the "Add To Cart" column after your columns that are bound to the database.  You probably have your databound columns set up as `BoundFields` like this:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Book Title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Book Author" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Book Price" />
</Columns>
```

Your "Add To Cart" column *will not* be databound.  If you just want to add a column that has a static button, you can add a `CommandField` to your `GridView`, like this:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Book Title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Book Author" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Book Price" />
    <asp:CommandField SelectText="Add To Cart" ShowSelectButton="True" />
</Columns>
```

Or you can just add `AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"` to your `GridView` markup.  Then you can handle the adding of items to your cart in the `RowCommand` or `SelectedIndexChanged` events that are fired when you click the Select button

Comment: thanks bro ...it solved the problem...but now column for  add to cart is at the beginning..that is before the table from the db.Can i place at the end of the gridview.  <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Add To Cart">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:ButtonField>
            

        </Columns>

Comment: @RajuSNair Hmm.  When you are using auto generated columns like that, I don't see a native way to change the order of the columns.  You could possibly add the column in code behind after it's databound (I'll add some code for that shortly).

Answer (score 0):

you can add column like this in gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField  >
   <HeaderTemplate  >
   <asp:Button ID="ButtonName" runat="server"  Text="Add to Cart" >   </asp:Button> 
</HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: ya, you are right. you use this also in template field             <ItemTemplate><asp:Button ID="ButtonName" runat="server"  Text="Add to Cart" >   </asp:Button> 
                                    
                                       
                                    </ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

Use the TemplateField column type -- unlimited customization: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">

    <EditItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>

    </EditItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```